# Rendering HTML in a background page in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to load and render a page in order to backup it and all resources loaded with it. I could parse the page, but I think that it is more efficient to be able to let the render engine requesting the resources and then intercepting them with [chrome.webrequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

So is there a way to render some html in a hidden tab, a background page, or something else?

Answer (score -1):

The only hidden tab you can manipulate is your background page.

You could possibly try to open the page in question in an iframe inside that page, but:

1. Some pages will not load properly in an iframe.
2. It's hard to predict how the renderer will actually work for a hidden page that's never intended to be swapped into a visible tab. There may be quirks.

All in all, client-side this is best done with [`pageCapture` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture).

Comment: PageCapture saves the whole page content as  binary mhtml which can then only be loaded in the main frame. So not usefull for me. I used phantomjs.